# display result in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having problem in displaying the result of this code to Sheet2. Is there a way to convert this code to have it displayed in a specific worksheet? Let say Sheet2?

> cell.Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = rowOffset

Here's the entire code:

```js
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range
    Dim rowOffset As Long

    With Worksheets("gaps").Range("A2:F2000")
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            rowOffset = 1
            Set f = .Find(what:=cell, after:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not f Is Nothing And f.Row <= cell.Row Then rowOffset = cell.Row - f.Row + 1
            
            cell.Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = rowOffset '<--| Modify this code to have it displayed in a specific worksheet
        
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + .Columns.Count + 1).Value = rowOffset
```